# div 11 não recebe estilização no css

Tags: html, css

Pessoal esta acontecendo uma coisa comigo que eu não estou entendendo

eu criei varias divs assim:

```
div id="nome"

img src="img/00001.jpg"

/div
```

para colocar uma imagem no fundo de uma pagina, mas como quero colocar algumas variaveis em cima dessa imagem coloquei o css dela assim:

```
#nome img{
    width:1100px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    height:730px;

    z-index: 0;

    }
```

o problema que quando coloco a decima segunda div com mesmo id ele não recebe o valor do css só até o decimo primeiro ja tentei de quase tudo.

obs:
Sei que pode ser uma pergunta boba, mas só estou perguntando aqui pq não achei em lugar nenhum a resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de ID tenta usar classe. o id só pode utilizar uma única vez por página.
Já as classe pode ser utilizada diversas vezes na mesma página.
no CSS terá que trocar * por .
sintaxe no html:
sintaxe no html:

```
<div class="nome">
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, Realmente dei mole mas antes de ver essa resposta de vcs eu já tinha alterado o id para class mas mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0):

> Por mais isso possa funcionar, isso não deviria.

Os `id` são feitos para serem únicos, somente um elemento deveria de ter um único `id`, [duplica-los é um erro](http://www.validator.pro/duplicate-id/#.WIkVjfkrKiM).

O seu código, como está, não será válido no [teste da W3C](https://validator.w3.org/). No final, isso indica que o seu website potencialmente terá comportamentos diferentes dependo do navegador que usuário utiliza. Um navegador pode aceitar isso normalmente, estilizando todos os elementos com o `id` duplicado, enquanto um outro pode apenas estilizar o primeiro elemento.

Uma alternativa fácil é trocar o `id` por `class`, de maneira a ficar:

```
.nome img{ ... }
```

Enquanto o HTML torna-se:

```
<div class="nome"> ... </div>
```

Além disso, o uso de `id` duplicado impede o uso de manipulação por Javascript, basicamente.